# CentOS - Network card suddenly unable to communicate with devices outside of the local subnet

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, hp-proliant, networkmanager

I have a CentOS 7 (previously CentOS 6) HP DL385p server which is connected via a single NIC (using SFP converter to copper) to the local LAN.

On top of that, it uses the F5 VPN client in order to poll information from a secure remote location.

It also has a docker container running Nginx with PHP.

The problem I'm seeing is as follows.

Server boots up, connects to network and is able to communicate with devices on the internet and also within internal LANs where permitted.

We then connect the F5 vpn, sure enough still able to reach the same as the devices but with the addition of the remotely secured devices via vpn.

This will be left running for a while and suddenly the server finds itself unable to communicate with anything other than the local subnet to which it is connected.

Examining the messages, dmesg and journalctl (`journalctl --this-boot --all --no-pager`) reveals nothing of obvious relevance other than the tun0 interface utilized by the f5 vpn as being 'removed'.

```
NetworkManager[1047]: <info>  (tun0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
```

However, the F5 vpn (f5fpc) reports making no change (it's sat waiting to reconnect) and whilst this is the only log shown (of any apparent relation to the issue), I believe this isn't the cause but simply a symptom of the problem.

What I mean, is that I believe the F5 vpn is disconnecting because the underlying requirement has gone - the ability to communicate outside the local subnet (including remote BIG-IP devices).

If I check the routing table of the server, routes appear fine - having a default route to a valid gateway device (which it still can reach).

Interface also shows as being correctly addressed and up and running in iproute2 and net-tools.

The quickest solution to temporarily resolve (without a predictable time frame for when it will next occur) is to run `systemctl restart networking` and then reconnect the F5 VPN once the connectivity is restored.

I'm a bit stumped and what to look at next and how I could possibly increase the verbosity in journalctl or from NetworkManager of what's happening.

*N.B: I referred to having CentOS 6 previously (not using NetworkManager) and the same thing happened there, I upgraded believing it was possibly the 2.6 Kernel or maybe older drivers. CentOS 7 seems to include sufficient be2net drivers for the NIC as seen in lsmod. I also mentioned docker just for sake of providing as much detail as possible (to the degree I'm permitted).*

Edit: I have posted over at devcentral in case the issue is related to the F5 VPN client - https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/linux-big-ip-vpn-client-disconnecting-but-potentially-taking-down-the-local-nic-in-its-process-47920

Edit 2:

Routing table without VPN:

`default via 192.168.3.254 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/22 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.22  metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1`

Routing table with:

`default via 192.168.3.254 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100
192.168.0.0/22 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.22  metric 100
192.168.3.254 via 192.168.0.22 dev eno1  proto none  metric 1
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.1.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.2.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.3.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.4.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.5.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.6.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.7.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
10.8.0.0/16 via 10.112.194.63 dev tun0  proto none  metric 1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
x.x.x.x via 192.168.3.254 dev eno1  proto none  metric 1`

Last IP removed for privacy.

Comment: How does the routing table look when the network is working correctly and the VPN is connected?

Comment: When connected to VPN the routing table has routes for the remote networks, a specific static added just to ensure the gateway persists via the physical NIC and one for the remote device we're connecting to using the vpn client. The last two of them routes are part of the clients design, not something we configure at the remote policy end.

I've added a copy of the routing table to the question (edited slightly, but remains intact logically).

Comment: Does the routing table look different when you are experiencing the connectivity problems?

Comment: No, it looks the same as "Routing table without VPN".
When the issue occurs, I can contact devices on the same LAN. This includes the gateway.